# React, how do I track that the user has stopped typing in the input?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have such a functional component. When a user enters input, I send a message to the server and output to other users what someone writes. Here is the code:

```
const ChatInput = (props) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const typingMessage = () =>{
    socket.emit('typing',props.username);
  }

  return (
    <div className>
      <Input
        value = {message}
        onChange = {
          (e) => typingMessage(e.target.value)
        }
        placeholder="Type a message here"
      />
      <Button
        onClick={sendMessage}
        icon={<SendOutlined />
        }/>

    </div>
  );
};
```

How do I track that the user has stopped writing? If he does not enter anything into the input for more than 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You need deboune function, that will count 10sec (it may be different time, depends on you) after last input (onChange trigger)

```
function debounce(func, timeout = 10000){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
function saveInput(){
  console.log('User has stopped writting 10 sec ago');
}
const processChange = debounce(() => saveInput());

const typingMessage = () =>{
    socket.emit('typing',props.username);
    processChange()

  }
```

Comment: how is this is solving the problem?

Comment: function saveInput will trigger after 10sec (it may be different time, depends on you) from latest trigger of onChange. Inside that saveInput function you can put any handler you want, but you will be confident that user has stopped typing.

Comment: `console.log('User has stopped writting 10 sec ago');` triggered many times, and not from the last change in the input

Comment: what timeout you putted in debounce function? can you paste your code?

Comment: I just copied your code into mine. and after 10 seconds, the message was displayed to me as many times as I entered characters with a slight delay

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `onFocus`, `onBlur`, and `onMouseLeave`, in such a way that when `onFocus` happens, he is writing, when `onBlur` happens, he is not writing anymore, and when `onMouseLeave` happens or when he clicks on send, you trigger `onBlur` yourself. Like below:

> I assumed that your `Input` component can forward `ref`. If not make it so by following [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

```
const ChatInput = (props) => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const typingMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("typing", props.username);
  };
  const notTypingMessage = () => {
    socket.emit("typing", "");
  };

  return (
    <div className>
      <Input
        ref={inputRef}
        value={message}
        onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => typingMessage()}
        onBlur={() => notTypingMessage()}
        onMouseLeave={() => inputRef?.current.blur()}
        placeholder="Type a message here"
      />
      <Button onClick={()=>{sendMessage(); inputRef?.current.blur()}} icon={<SendOutlined />} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default ChatInput;
```

Comment: if the cursor remains in the input, it will be assumed that the user still writes

Comment: Yeah, and for me it's logic. If I have focus, I'm writing, if I click outside or if I just move away with my cursor, I'm not writing anymore. That's what the code above does.

Comment: Also, call this `inputRef?.current.blur()` when you click on send button, this way you trigger blur when he send its message.

Answer (score 0):

- This is a one solution waiting for a second after finish typing and emits `stoppedTyping` event.
- you may still want to optimize it according to the your applications needs

```js
const emit = (action, data) => {
  console.log(action, data)
}


function App() {
  const props = { username: 'me' }
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (message && !isTyping) {
      emit('stoppedTyping', props.username)
    }
  }, [isTyping])

  const typingMessage = (v) => {
    emit('typing', props.username);
    setMessage(v)
  }

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
  }

  return (
    <div className=''>
      <input
        value={message}
        onKeyDown={() => !isTyping && setIsTyping(true)}
        onKeyUp={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            setIsTyping((t) => t ? false : t)
          }, 1000)

        }}
        onChange={
          (e) => typingMessage(e.target.value)
        }
        placeholder="Type a message here"
      />
      <button
        onClick={sendMessage}
      >send</button>
      <pre>{
        JSON.stringify({ message, isTyping })
      }</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```